# Run Makefiles in symlink directories from python

Tags: python, makefile

I have a directory `~/PROJECTS` containing several subdirectories,
some of them being symlinks to other directories.

```
.
├── proj1_symlink_dir
├── proj2_symlink_dir
├── proj3_symlink_dir
├── backup_1_dir
├── backup_2_dir
```

Each of these symlink directories (which point to other directories
on my hard drive) i.e.
`[proj1_symlink_dir, proj2_symlink_dir, proj3_symlink_dir]`
each contains a `Makefile`.

I want to write a `python` script to:

1. Loop through only the symlinks in the active directory
2. For each of these symlinks go into the directory and run `make clean` (or allowing for a string parameter containing the make commands)

Could anyone please assist in writing a compact pythonic
script to help perform the above task?

So far I have the following to print the symlinks (adapted from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/Utility/Findsymboliclinksandshowwheretheypointto.htm)):

```
dirname = os.getcwd()
for name in os.listdir(dirname):
    if name not in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
        full = os.path.join(dirname, name)
        if os.path.islink(full):
            print(name, '->', os.readlink(full))
```

I'm not sure how to deal with running `Makefile` commands in python
safely

**Update**

With @Marat's help, I've now created the following script called
`runmke.py`.

```
#!/Usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import os
import json

def run_symlink_makefile_cmd(dirname, make_cmds, verbose):
    """
    Run common make commands from makefiles from 
    all symlinked directories that are located 
    in a specified directory
    """
    make_cmds_str = " ".join(make_cmds)
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        if name not in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
            full = os.path.join(dirname, name)
            if os.path.islink(full):
                if verbose:
                    print(f"\n>>>>> Running the Make command:")
                    print(f"make -C {full} {make_cmds_str}")
                os.system(f"make -C {full} {make_cmds_str}")

def main(dirname, make_cmds, verbose):
    # Display parameters passed for the given run (includes defaults)
    print(f"""The parameters for this run are:\n {json.dumps(locals(), indent=2, default=str)}""")
    run_symlink_makefile_cmd(dirname=dirname,
                             make_cmds=make_cmds,
                             verbose=verbose)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dirname', action='store', default=os.getcwd(),
                        help='The directory in which symlink directories, default is the current directory')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--make_cmds', nargs='+',
                        default=["clean", "latex_style"],
                        help='These are the Makefile commands to run')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=True,
                        help='If true, print updates while processing.')
    argument_parsed = parser.parse_args()

    main(
        dirname=argument_parsed.dirname,
        make_cmds=argument_parsed.make_cmds,
        verbose=argument_parsed.verbose
    )
```

However when I run `./runmke.py -m latex_style -v False`
in my terminal I get the error:

```
usage: runmke.py [-h] [-d DIRNAME] [-m MAKE_CMDS [MAKE_CMDS ...]] [-v]
runmke.py: error: unrecognized arguments: False
```

Any ideas why the `verbose` logical argument is not being recognized.
It works, when I don't pass this in manually.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Marat - I've added some more details of where I'm at

Comment: it seems you are only missing one line below the print statement: `os.system('make -C "%s" clean' % full)`

Comment: @Marat - many thanks for your kind help. I have added my updated code with your assist as a script in my original post. This has a slight error. Could you please assist? If you write back as a full answer I can accept it so that you get the due credit for the solution

Comment: `action=store_true` type arguments don't have value, they are set to True if the key merely presents in the command. So, the correct command to run is: `./runmke.py -m latex_style -v`

Comment: also, protip: verboseness is better to be used with `logging`

Comment: @Marat - Thanks for the clarification. I would like to add the solution below so that it may benefit others. I will credit you in solution, for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Marat's help, I've now created the following script called
`runmke.py`.

```
#!/Usr/bin/env python

import argparse
import os
import json

def run_symlink_makefile_cmd(dirname, make_cmds, verbose):
    """
    Run common make commands from makefiles from 
    all symlinked directories that are located 
    in a specified directory
    """
    make_cmds_str = " ".join(make_cmds)
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        if name not in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
            full = os.path.join(dirname, name)
            if os.path.islink(full):
                if verbose:
                    print(f"\n>>>>> Running the Make command:")
                    print(f"make -C {full} {make_cmds_str}")
                os.system(f"make -C {full} {make_cmds_str}")

def main(dirname, make_cmds, verbose):
    # Display parameters passed for the given run (includes defaults)
    print(f"""The parameters for this run are:\n {json.dumps(locals(), indent=2, default=str)}""")
    run_symlink_makefile_cmd(dirname=dirname,
                             make_cmds=make_cmds,
                             verbose=verbose)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dirname', action='store', default=os.getcwd(),
                        help='The directory in which symlink directories, default is the current directory')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--make_cmds', nargs='+',
                        default=["clean", "latex_style"],
                        help='These are the Makefile commands to run')
    parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true', default=True,
                        help='If true, print updates while processing.')
    argument_parsed = parser.parse_args()

    main(
        dirname=argument_parsed.dirname,
        make_cmds=argument_parsed.make_cmds,
        verbose=argument_parsed.verbose
    )
```

It can be run at the terminal using `./runmke.py -m latex_style -v`